# INER JOIN error

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I would like to go for Inner join and getting the bellow error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN ( SELECT Chalanits.Chalanit_partno, Chalanits.Chalanit_qty FROM Chala' at line 7

```
SELECT Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`, Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_unitprice`, Chalanits.Chalanit_qty
FROM Cuspoit 
WHERE Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` =
(
SELECT Chalanits.Chalanit_cuspoid FROM Chalanits WHERE Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-1306001' LIMIT 1
)
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Chalanits.Chalanit_partno, Chalanits.Chalanit_qty
FROM Chalanits 
WHERE Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-1306001')
ON Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`= Chalanits.Chalanit_partno
```

Can anyone help me to find the mistake??

Comment: For more information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use that SQL:

```
SELECT Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`, Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_unitprice`, Chalanits.Chalanit_qty
FROM Cuspoit
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Chalanits.Chalanit_partno, Chalanits.Chalanit_qty
FROM Chalanits 
WHERE Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-1306001')
ON Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`= Chalanits.Chalanit_partno 
WHERE Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` =
(
SELECT Chalanits.Chalanit_cuspoid FROM Chalanits WHERE Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-    1306001' LIMIT 1
)
```

You have inverted the WHERE and THE INNER JOIN comand

Answer (score 1):

Where clauses come after all of the joins.  And when you use a subquery inteh where clause try using IN instead of =.

Comment: In his case the `=` instead of `IN` is fine, because of the `LIMIT 1`. But it does smell bad... xD

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the `WHERE` clause should come after `INNER JOIN`.

But, beside that, seems you are using sub-queries where you really don't need it.

```
SELECT Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`, Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_unitprice`, Chalanits.Chalanit_qty
FROM Cuspoit 
INNER JOIN Chalanits ON Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`= Chalanits.Chalanit_partno
WHERE Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` = (
    SELECT Chalanits.Chalanit_cuspoid FROM Chalanits WHERE Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-1306001' LIMIT 1
)
AND Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-1306001'
```

Also, the subquery that still remains looks really odd, because it gets a possibly random register (which depends on PKs and UKs) because of the LIMIT with no sort. If you want `Chalanits` rows with same `cuspoid` **and** `partno` of `Cuspoit` table, then you want this:

```
SELECT Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`, Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_unitprice`, Chalanits.Chalanit_qty
FROM Cuspoit 
INNER JOIN Chalanits
    ON Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_partno`= Chalanits.Chalanit_partno
       AND Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid = Chalanits.Chalanit_cuspoid
WHERE Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-1306001'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an INNER JOIN after the WHERE Clause

```
WHERE Cuspoit.`Cuspoit_cuspoid` =
(
SELECT Chalanits.Chalanit_cuspoid FROM Chalanits WHERE Chalanits.Chalanit_chalanid='CX-1306001' LIMIT 1
)
INNER JOIN (
```

Here is the error